# Have page scroll to the bottom when according opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an accordion-style menu that runs along the left side of my page.  This is the script that I have written for each separate accordion button (they're stacked on each other):

```
$("a.about-us").on('click', function(eve) {  
    eve.preventDefault();  
    $(this).toggleClass("down");
    $("ul.about-us").toggle()
});
```

I would like to have my page automatically scroll down to show a newly opened accordion if that open accordion extends beyond the bottom of the viewport.

This is what my HTML looks like for one of the buttons:
[HTML for About Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsjVU.png)

Answer (score 0):

on the accordion parent add the css:

```
height:auto;
```

If you need further help please provide the HTML structure.

Comment: I tried doing that, but it didn't work.  The accordions are extending the page, but the page doesn't scroll down like I would like them to.  You can go to http://www.typospotting.com/raja-ampat/ if you want to see what I'm working on

Comment: I included a screenshot of the HTML in the description above

Comment: @JackVawdrey It works for me. the page extends with the accordion. Have you fixed it or am I misunderstanding your issue?

Comment: The page does extend like I want it to, but what I want is for the page to automatically scroll down when the according reaches below the viewport